# Android + Phonegap/Cordova + Sencha : Drag/scrolling

Tags: android, html, cordova, sencha-touch

I am developping a Sencha Touch App using phonegap in Eclipse, testing on multiple android devices (Android 2.3 - 4.0, for exemple the galaxy nexus GT-i9250M). I am using a basic Sencha List. Now heres the problem (happens most times, on most devices). When i scroll down the list, i get this warning in the logcat :

05-18 13:01:26.414: W/webview(20422): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.

And the dragging gesture seems to not be registered at all when this happens, resulting in a very unpleasant scrolling motion. Small swipes work pretty well, its really the drag that causes problems (basically just freezes)...

Previous research tells me this is a recurrent android bug, but i couldn't find any solution nor workaround working for me anywhere. Tried a few things as stated here : http://uihacker.blogspot.ca/2010/10/android-bug-miss-drag-as-we-are-waiting.html

EDIT : 
Also tried this technique from the same person as above, catching the touchstart event both with the sencha event system (itemtouchstart), and on the document. 
http://uihacker.blogspot.ca/2011/01/android-touchmove-event-bug.html

But without success,

Anyone any sugestion? Workaround? Anything?

Thank you!

Comment: I am also facing the same problem..is there any solution??